# React native ex-navigation changing routers

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ex-navigation

I have a problem in switching pages with react-native ex-navigation:
Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigator'

this is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View, Navigator, Button } from 'react-native';
import {createRouter, NavigationProvider, StackNavigation, TabNavigation,TabNavigationItem as TabItem,}from '@exponent/ex-navigation';
import * as firebase from "firebase";

firebase.initializeApp(config);

import Login from 'auth/firstPage'
var Register = require('auth/register')
var Tab = require('./src/components/tab/mainTab');

const Router = createRouter(() => ({
  login: () => Login,
  register: () => Register,
  tab: () => Tab,
}));

export default class main extends Component {

  componentWillMount(){
    this.setState({ name:'login'});
  } 

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: 'tab'
    };
  }

  render(){
    return(
     <NavigationProvider router={Router}>
       <StackNavigation initialRoute={Router.getRoute(this.state.name)} />
     </NavigationProvider>
   )
 }
}
```

this is the code I used to navigate: `this.props.navigator.push({name:'register'})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you call this.props.navigator in another function in your new page component?

You will need to add the following in your new page constructor which gives you access to this.props.navigator:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.FUNCTION_CALL_NAV = this.FUNCTION_CALL_NAV.bind(this);
}

FUNCTION_CALL_NAV() {
  this.navigator.push({name: 'register'});
}
```

Comment: Thats work but now it gives me an error : Route is null or malformed.

Comment: I suggest you create a separated file in root folder called route.js and put all your routes in it. Then on the top of each component whenever you need to use router function, just import Routes from 'route'.